# The form has been closed [Sharepoint 2007 - Workflow - infopath]

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-2007, infopath, infopath-2007

I'm developping a workflow with MOSS 2007 and infopath and I got this error :

```
The form has been closed
```

This error occurs when I start a task. So I bind my new demand with my workflow then I try to do the first task and I get this message on a blank page.

In the LOGS file, I have this :

```
11/23/2010 08:53:13.71  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x09C0)                       0x0E54  Windows SharePoint Services     Topology                        0   Medium      Adding DEV\sspaccount to local group 2.  
11/23/2010 08:53:13.71  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x09C0)                       0x0E54  Windows SharePoint Services     Topology                        0   Medium      Adding DEV\sspaccount to local group 0.  
11/23/2010 08:53:13.82  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x09C0)                       0x0E54  Office Server                   Setup and Upgrade               8u3j    High        Registry key value {SearchThrottled} was not found under registry hive {Software\Microsoft\Office Server\12.0}. Assuming search sku is not throttled.    
11/23/2010 08:53:13.84  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x09C0)                       0x0E54  Search Server Common            MS Search Administration        90gf    Medium      SQL: dbo.proc_MSS_PropagationGetQueryServers     
11/23/2010 08:53:13.85  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x09C0)                       0x0E54  Search Server Common            MS Search Administration        8wni    High        Resuming default catalog with reason 'GPR_PROPAGATION' for application 'SharedServices1'...  
11/23/2010 08:53:13.85  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x09C0)                       0x0E54  Search Server Common            MS Search Administration        8wnj    High        Resuming anchor text catalog with reason GPR_PROPAGATION' for application 'SharedServices1'...   
11/23/2010 08:53:13.89  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x09C0)                       0x0E54  Search Server Common            MS Search Administration        8dvl    Medium      Search application '620821f2-b841-4af8-8f46-8f7c559c8159': Provision start addresses in default content source.  
11/23/2010 08:53:13.90  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x09C0)                       0x0E54  Search Server Common            MS Search Administration        7hmh    High        exception in SearchUpgradeProvisioner Keyword Config System.InvalidOperationException: jobServerSearchServiceInstance is null     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchUpgradeProvisioner..ctor(SearchServiceInstance searchServiceInstance)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.OSSPrimaryGathererProject.ProvisionContentSources()  
11/23/2010 08:53:13.90  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x09C0)                       0x0E54  Windows SharePoint Services     Topology                        0   Medium      Adding DEV\sspaccount to local group 2.  
11/23/2010 08:53:13.90  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x09C0)                       0x0E54  Windows SharePoint Services     Topology                        0   Medium      Adding DEV\sspaccount to local group 0.  
11/23/2010 08:53:14.54  w3wp.exe (0x0D38)                           0x10F4  Forms Server                    Forms Services Runtime          82fp    Warning     Exception occurred during request processing. (User: DEV\Administrator, Form Name: , IP: , Request: http://sharepoint2007/_layouts/WrkTaskIP.aspx?List=567f9e25-6d92-441b-862d-54a2f94ca3fc&ID=4&Source=http://sharepoint2007/_layouts/WrkStat.aspx?List=%257bE07DD388%252d6DF3%252d46E2%252dB883%252d88E002E9370E%257d&WorkflowInstanceID=%257b950E0922%252dAF43%252d4D6E%252d9E43%252d7D3C22F30864%257d, Form ID: , Type: InfoPathLocalizedException, Exception Message: The specified form cannot be found.)  
11/23/2010 08:53:17.37  w3wp.exe (0x0D38)                           0x10F4  SharePoint Portal Server        Runtime                         8gp7    Medium      Topology cache updated. (AppDomain: /LM/W3SVC/1720149840/Root-1-129349722719375000)  
11/23/2010 08:53:23.73  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x09C0)                       0x09DC  Excel Services                  Excel Services Administration   8tqi    Medium      ExcelServerSharedWebApplication.Synchronize: Starting synchronize for instance of Excel Services in SSP 'SharedServices1'.   
11/23/2010 08:53:23.73  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x09C0)                       0x09DC  Excel Services                  Excel Services Administration   8tqj    Medium      ExcelServerSharedWebApplication.Synchronize: Successfully synchronized instance of Excel Services in SSP 'SharedServices1'.
```

The xsn file is added and installed on the server. When I go to Central Administration > Application Management > Manage Form Templates, the form is there and marked as Ready.

Do you have any idea of my problem ?

Cheers
Skilpit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys I resolved it. It's seems it was a conflict about URN. I copy-paste it from my infopath properties and reinstall all the web app and it works now... Weard :-)